# Node.js copy file EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, windows, copy, filesystems

I try to copy a font with `nodejs v14.17.0` to `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` , when try with prompt I don't have problem

```bash
copy /B "Haloha Free Trial.ttf" /V %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\
    1 file(s) copied.
```

but when try with nodejs, I've this issue

```bash
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'D:\dev\test\javascript\font\Haloha Free Trial.ttf' -> 'C:\Users\omen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: 'D:\\dev\\test\\javascript\\font\\Haloha Free Trial.ttf',
  dest: 'C:\\Users\\omen\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts'
}
```

This is my code

```js
let options = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(options[0]);

console.log(process.env.LOCALAPPDATA);
const locallAppdata = process.env.LOCALAPPDATA;

const fs = require('fs');

fs.copyFile( options[0], locallAppdata+'\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\', (err) =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log( argv[0] + " was copied ");
});
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: When you copy the file using prompt, did you run the prompt as administrator ?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh I use [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) as prompt but with current user (no administrator )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In according with official documentation **[fs.copyFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesrc-dest-mode-callback)**

- src <string> | <Buffer> | <URL> source **filename** to copy
- dest <string> | <Buffer> | <URL> destination **filename** of the copy operation

In **dest** is required destination **filename** and not only destination directory.

```
fs.copyFile(src, dest[, mode], callback)
```

In this case **dest** = **'locallAppdata+'\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\'** + **options[0]**

```
let dest = locallAppdata+'\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\' + options[0];
let src =  options[0];
    
 fs.copyFile( src, dest, (err) =>{
     if(err) throw err;
             console.log( options[0] + " was copied ");
 });
```

Comment: Permission error on a malformed destination path is kind of evil, especially when it's legitimate to think that the destination folder should be enough (as the file could keep it's old name). Anyways, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**This is how to recursively copy files from one directory to another**

```
import { copyFileSync, mkdirSync, readdirSync, statSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const SOURCE_PATH = `libs/models/src/lib/template/sample`;
const TARGET_PATH = SOURCE_PATH.replace('sample', 'product');
const DIRS = readdirSync(SOURCE_PATH);

function isFile(target: string) {
  return statSync(target).isFile();
}

function copyFile(source: string, target: string) {
  copyFileSync(source, target);
  return;
}

function copyFiles(source: string, target: string) {
  const dirs = readdirSync(source);
  for (const d of dirs) {
    if (isFile(join(source, d))) {
      copyFile(join(source, d), join(target, d));
    } else {
      mkdirSync(join(target, d));
      copyFiles(join(source, d), join(target, d));
    }
  }
}

copyFiles(SOURCE_PATH, TARGET_PATH);
```